# Get data from a file and convert it to dictionary in unity using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

i am trying to read from a file and convert it into dictionary in unity using c#.The file contains data like

```
1 1 1 acsbd 
1 2 1 123ws
```

here i want to make the first 6 characters to the key and rest characters as values.

here is the code i tried(it is mostly from stackoverflow)

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader (
  @"D:\Programming\Projects\Launch pad\itnol\KeySound");


     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         char[] line1 = line.ToCharArray();
         if (line1.Length >= 11)
         {
             line1[5] = ':';
             line = line1.ToString();
             //Console.WriteLine(line);
         }
         var items = line.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }));

         Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         foreach (var item in items)
         {
             Debug.Log(item[0]);
             dict.Add(item[0], item[1]);
         }
```

It complies but gives `IndexOutOfRangeException` *exception* thrown on run time

Thank you.

Comment: Okay. Then do it. What's the question?

Comment: i want to know how to do it

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Did you read [ask]?

Comment: i edited the question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

string fileName = @"D:\Programming\Projects\Launch pad\itnol\KeySound";

...

Dictionary<string, string> dict = File 
  .ReadLines(fileName)    
  .Where(line => line.Length >= 11)           // If you want to filter out lines 
  .ToDictionary(line => line.Substring(0, 6), // Key:   first 6 characters
                line => line.Substring(6));   // Value: rest characters
```

**Edit**: No *Linq*, no `File` version:

```
string fileName = @"D:\Programming\Projects\Launch pad\itnol\KeySound";

...

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Do not forget to wrap IDisposable into using
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName)) {
  while (true) {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();

    if (null == line)
      break;
    else if (line.Length >= 11) 
      dict.Add(line.Substring(0, 6), line.Substring(6));
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't now if this works but it looks nice and simple

Comment: thanks for help but visual studio says `System.IO.File does not contain definition for ReadLines`

Comment: @rishabh kunda: `ReadLines` (please, notice the last `s`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry it was a typo in my comment, in code its `ReadLines` and it still gives the same error

Comment: @rishabh kunda: OK, let's implement no *Linq*, no `File` version (see my edit). There's no need in `ToCharArray` and `Split`, but `Substring`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you, i was looking for a solution for weeks before posting it here...thanks again